# Rebuild dependant target after a custom target runs

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a CMake project that uses an external tool to build special libraries for a certain platform. Running this tool uses a "config file" to generate several files that are injected into the compiler and linker options when the final program is built:

- An object library
- A linker command file that links in several pre-compiled libs and the above object library
- A makefile options file that sets various platform compiler options

whenever any of these files change, the main program must be entirely rebuilt, as they are intrinsic parts of the program and involve things like compiler flags and system includes.

So far, I have something like this, which [appears](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-March/035621.html) to be a recommended way:

```
# run the external build tool to generate platform libs
# and compiler/linker option files
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${LINKER_CMD_FILE} ${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE} ${PLATFORM_OBJECT_LIB}
    COMMAND "${EXTERNAL_BUILD_TOOL}"
    ARGS --config ${CFG_FILE}
    DEPENDS ${CFG_FILE}
    COMMENT "Invoking external build tool for ${CFG_FILE}"
)

add_custom_target(platform_libs
    DEPENDS ${LINKER_CMD_FILE} ${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE} ${PLATFORM_OBJECT_LIB}
)

....

add_executable(main_prog
    main.c
)

# whenever any of these change, rebuild
add_dependencies(main_prog platform_libs)

# add the platform compiler opts from the generated file
target_compile_options(main_prog PRIVATE
    @${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE}
)
```

This is also pretty much what is done [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914497/why-doesnt-cmake-detect-dependency-on-my-generated-file).

When I change the config file, the `platform_libs` target runs and generates the library and other files as needed. However, although running `make main_prog` does trigger the build of the `platform_libs` correctly, it does not appear to "notice" any changes and therefore concludes it doesn't need to actually re-build the main program.

I can always run `make clean`, but it's not great to have CMake totally blind to fundamental system libraries changing.

How can I force `main_prog` to rebuild if `platform_libs` has run?

Comment: Perhaps, you haven't shown all of your code, but shouldn't the `add_dependencies()` call be on `main_prog`, not `main_app`?

Comment: @squareskittles sorry, that's a typo. The real targets have different names.

Comment: Try doing something along `set_target_property(main_prog LINK_DEPENDS ${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE})` or with `platform_libs`

Comment: @KamilCuk that does indeed always force a re-link, though it doesn't force a re-build of the source files (i.e. `main.c`), which might now have different compiler options.

Comment: Och, because when `COMPILER_OPTS_FILE` changes then all the sources of `main_prog` need to be rebuild. Ok, sorry I missed that. Try that: set dependency on the source file itself. Iterate over the files in `main_prog`  `get_target_property(main_prog SOURCES sources)` and do `set_source_files_properties(${sources} OBJECT_DEPENDS ${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE})` for each of the sources. I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer's central method comes from @KamilCuk's answer in the comment of the question].

The trick is to use one of:

- Set the `LINK_DEPENDS` property on the downstream target (`main_prog` in the example) - this means if the file in this property changes, a re-link will be performed.
- Set the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` on every source used for `main_prog`.

In my case, because the `${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE}` affects every file's compilation, I needed the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` method. If you do this you don't really need `LINK_DEPENDS` since you'll recompile your sources and re-link anyway, but I did both for clarity of meaning. In theory you could engineer a situation where the linker command file changes, but not the compiler opts, in which case you might miss a re-link.

In my case, I needed to do this for not only `main_prog` but also all the other libraries `main_prog` used, so I stored the linker command files and the compiler opts file as target properties on the `platform_libs` target:

```
set_property(TARGET platform_libs
    PROPERTY MY_LINKER_CMD_FILE ${LINKER_CMD_FILE}
)
set_property(TARGET platform_libs
    PROPERTY MY_COMPILER_OPTS_FILE ${COMPILER_OPTS_FILE}
)
```

This means it's easy to pull them out later, without having to know the exact file names (or even have access to the variables themselves):

```
# Retrieve the previously-stored options
# To do this, we only need the target name and the (fixed) property name
get_target_property(MY_LINKER_CMD platform_libs MY_LINKER_CMD_FILE)
get_target_property(MY_COMPILER_OPTS platform_libs MY_COMPILER_OPTS_FILE)

set_target_properties(main_prog PROPERTIES
    LINK_DEPENDS ${MY_LINKER_CMD}
)

# Also set as the linker cmd on the linker command line
# This depends on the linker, for GCC it's -Wl,T<file>
target_link_libraries(main_prog PRIVATE
    -Wl,-T${MY_LINKER_CMD}
)

# these are the sources that depend on the opts file
get_target_property(MAIN_SRCS main_prog SOURCES)

# set the dependency of source files on platform_libs
set_property(SOURCE ${MAIN_SRCS}
    PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS ${MY_COMPILER_OPTS}
)
# Set as a compiler opt file
# For GCC: @<opt_file>
target_compile_options(${TARGET_TO_COMPILE} PRIVATE
    @${MY_COMPILER_OPTS}
)

# make sure the platform_libs is a dep
# or the compiler opts and linker files won't be generated
add_dependencies(main_prog platform_libs)
```

Notably, in this Cmake code, the project names `main_prog` and `platform_libs` can be variables, and then you can make the whole thing into a function that just needs those two project names. This makes it easy to reuse the code for compiling libraries against `platform_libs` library.